# Apex Class Line Error

Tags: apex

Hi I'm getting this error on the code below:

> Error: Compile Error: Comparison arguments must be compatible types:
>   User, String at line 147 column 15

Can anyone help with the last line (147)?

```
    if(currentCase.RecordTypeId == custReqRecType.Id 
       && currentCase.Status == '01-New' 
       && currentCase.Kinnser_closed_on_create__c == FALSE
       && currentCase.Email__c != NULL
       && currentCase.Do_Not_Send_Case_Email__c == FALSE
       && currentCase.CreatedBy != 'Client Services Integrations'){
```

Comment: And also make sure you have queried `currentCase.CreatedBy.Name`.

Answer (score 5):

It needs to be `currentCase.CreatedBy.Name` when you do `currentCase.CreatedBy` it is expecting the `User` object.

Comment: @Heather - When an answer solves your problem you can Thank the person who answered by uprooting and accepting the answer. Both you and the person who answered get +rep for that. More importantly, it helps others with similar questions find answers.

Answer (score 2):

Use currentCase.CreatedBy.name

createdby is storing an id of a related record so you need to specify the field in the related record that you want to compare

Comment: Technically the CreatedBy is a User object. If it was an Id the string comparison would be valid and throw a runtime 'Invalid Id" error and not a compile time error.